# Problems with arrays of unspecified lengths

Tags: c, types, initialization

I'm writing an IrDA stack in c and implementing the Information Access Service component and i need a lookup table for class/key/value pairs. To keep it in an orderly format, I'm trying to put it all into one initialiser. the following code works just fine and compiles the data to compact linked tables in ROM.

```
#define IAS_PTYPE_STRING 0x00
#define IAS_PTYPE_BYTE   0x01

typedef struct {
    UBYTE* name;
    UBYTE  type;
    UBYTE* value;
} IAS_Attrib_t ;

typedef IAS_Attrib_t* IAS_Attrib_List_t[];

typedef struct {
    UBYTE* name;
    IAS_Attrib_List_t* attributes;
} IAS_Class_t;

static const IAS_Class_t IAS_Database[] = {
    {"IrDA:IrCOMM",
        &(IAS_Attrib_List_t){
            &(IAS_Attrib_t){"Parameters", IAS_PTYPE_STRING, "IrDA:TinyTP:LsapSel"},
            NULL,
        },
    },
};
```

However I'm having trouble getting the data back out. according to the types used, i should be able to do something like this:

```
UBYTE class = 1;
UBYTE attr = 1;
UBYTE* name = (*(IAS_Database[class].attributes))[attr]->name;
```

this is because

- `IAS_Database[class].attributes` is type `IAS_Attrib_List_t*`
- `*(IAS_Database[class].attributes)` is type `IAS_Attrib_List_t` i.e. `IAS_Attrib_t*[]`
- `(*(IAS_Database[class].attributes))[attr]` should be type `IAS_Attrib_t*`
- `(*(IAS_Database[class].attributes))[attr]->name` should be type `UBYTE*`

however when i try to query the table, i get `invalid use of array with unspecified bounds` back from mspgcc. Even a hack like `(IAS_Attrib_t*)((IAS_Database[class].attributes)+(sizeof(IAS_Attrib_t)*attr))` fails until i cast the db to void like `(IAS_Attrib_t*)((void*)(IAS_Database[class].attributes)+(sizeof(IAS_Attrib_t)*attr))` however this just feels so dirty. I'd really like to figure out the correct syntax to do it the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. 
In my utter frustration it seems i tried every variant bar the one I put up here. `(*(IAS_Database[class].attributes))[attr]` does indeed work properly and even works when expressed as `(*IAS_Database[class].attributes)[attr]` i believe the compiler was incorrectly assuming that the first pointer (being to a UBYTE**) was actually a list and was trying to apply the index to a pointer type (where the type is incomplete).

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef IAS_Attrib_t* IAS_Attrib_List_t[];
```

why are you using these brackets ? use a number inside or remove them

Comment: i am using the brackets because the length of the list is not the same across all instances of the IAS_Attrib_List_t type, hence cannot be placed in the brackets.

Comment: I thought it's not legal to have undefined number of elements in an array


#include <stdio.h>

struct s {
    int a, b, c;
};

typedef struct s *p[];

int main(void)
{
    
    return 0;
}

Comment: it is legal to have undefined number of elements in c99, but there are restrictions, and the compiler won't allocate memory for that reference. the place where it is most useful is typedefs where you want the compiler to know how big each member of the array is but not how many elements.